# Sencha Touch 2 HtmlEditor

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I was wondering how to use the HTML Editor from Ext JS 4 in Sencha Touch 2, or if there is any way to use a non-plain-text editor. Does Sencha plaining to support it on Sencha Touch 2 also?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the ExtJS HTML editor with Sencha Touch. I seriously doubt adding that as a field class in Sencha Touch is a consideration of the dev team. You would need to write your own custom class for this. I would start with extending the Ext.field.TextArea class and go from there. If you're not sure how to do this, start here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/class_system

Answer (score 0):

There is no html editor as it would be a pain to use on a mobile device.